# How to match data from database using regular expression?

Tags: mysql, regex, sqlite

I stored regular expression in MySQL (or SQLite3) database column like:

[image: Database column screenshot]

```
qus | ans
----- |  -----
(hii?|hell?o) | Hello There...
```

Now if input match hi or hii or helo or hello then answer return Hello There

```
if(input == "hi" /*or hii*/){
  return ans; //ans = Hello There
}
```

It's possible? if yes how can I do this?

Comment: You probably want to look at the `RLIKE` or `REGEXP` sql statements - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: I already tried.

Answer (score 3):

The regexp can come from a table column instead of being a literal:

```
CREATE TABLE regexps (
    re VARCHAR(99)
);
INSERT INTO regexps (re)
    VALUES ('hii?|hell?o'), ('aloha'), ('bonjour');

SELECT CONCAT('matches ', re)
    FROM regexps
    WHERE "hi, y'all" REGEXP re;
SELECT CONCAT('matches ', re)
    FROM regexps
    WHERE "bonjour and aloha" REGEXP re;
SELECT CONCAT('matches ', re)
    FROM regexps
    WHERE "oops: high" REGEXP re;
```

...

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM regexps;
+-------------+
| re          |
+-------------+
| hii?|hell?o |
| aloha       |
| bonjour     |
+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>     SELECT CONCAT('matches ', re)
    ->         FROM regexps
    ->         WHERE "hi, y'all" REGEXP re;
+------------------------+
| CONCAT('matches ', re) |
+------------------------+
| matches hii?|hell?o    |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>     SELECT CONCAT('matches ', re)
    ->         FROM regexps
    ->         WHERE "bonjour and aloha" REGEXP re;
+------------------------+
| CONCAT('matches ', re) |
+------------------------+
| matches aloha          |
| matches bonjour        |
+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>     SELECT CONCAT('matches ', re)
    ->         FROM regexps
    ->         WHERE "oops: high" REGEXP re;
+------------------------+
| CONCAT('matches ', re) |
+------------------------+
| matches hii?|hell?o    |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> I want to match only hi or hii or helo or hello, tnen answer with "Hello There"

`re` is `hii?|hell?o`, `answer` is `Hello There`.  The query is

```
SELECT answer FROM regexps WHERE $input REGEXP re LIMIT 1
```

I add the `LIMIT` because you might have a situation where two different regexps match.

Comment: I want to match only hi or hii or helo or hello

Comment: if input = hi then match hi and ans= Hello There

Comment: @Rabib - OK, add another column and see what I added to my Answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [preg match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [preg replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to test your regex

Example:

```
$input = 'hii user';
$output = 'Hi there';
// If your regex matches
if(preg_match('/(hii?|hell?o)/', $input))
{
    // succes;
    // Replace the input by your answer
    echo preg_replace('/(hii?|hell?o)/', $output, $input); // returns Hi there user
}
else
{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: Similarly it's possible for Database?

Comment: Sure but your question was referring to PHP. If you want to do it through a query please read the following: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx

Comment: I already tried **RLIKE** **LIKE** **REGEXP** . But I can't understand how to get **Hello There if input = hi** and database **column = hii?** . I new at php so if possible please give a example please.

Comment: Refer to my example above. Replace `(hii?|hell?o)`  and `$output = 'Hi there';` with a result from a select query

Comment: Example please.